# [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)

Tags: kernel, kernel-panic

When trying to boot a SLES 12, we got the following kernel panic issue:

[Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)

**Q:** Could it be a HW issue? Or a SW issue? How to debug it?

Comment: seems related: https://community.hpe.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/ML350-G9-BIOS-has-corrupted-hw-PMU-resources-MSR-38d-is-330/td-p/6831360

Comment: same message, but no kernel panic for them.

Answer (score 1):

Linux wants to access Performance Counter while server already accessed performance counter to checking hardwares.
Be sure that its safe and you can ignore it.